# validation for empty or null input field

Tags: javascript, validation, isnullorempty

I need to check if the value of field `patientid` is empty or null and print an alert.

Somehow the code below is not working:

```
<td width="75">Patient ID<font color="red">*</font></td>
<td width="166"><form:input path="patientid"/></td>
```

Could you please help me out?

Comment: `<form:input path="patientid"/>` ? Could that be jsp or something vague? Never seen it..

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form:input path="patientid"/>` is not html.

This should get you started:

```
<td width="75">Patient ID<font color="red">*</font></td>
<td width="166"><input type="text" id="patientid" onchange="
   this.value==='' && alert( 'I am empty' );
"/></td>
```

Or you could try to do this:

```
<td width="75">Patient ID<font color="red">*</font></td>
<td width="166"><input type="text" id="patientid" onchange="
   this.value==='' && (this.value='I cannot be empty');
"/></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a input value is empty just do the following:

```
    if(document.getElementById("yourInputsId").value !=""){
      //do stuff if its not empty}
    else{
     //do other Stuff
    }
```